# beginner wanting to remove gimp

Tags: software-center, gimp

I installed GIMP to make a Christmas card and now everytime I try to open LibreOffice, GIMP opens instead. I can right clip on the file and use the "choose program" to select LibreOffice, but this is a major nuisance. I just want LO to open my document files and spreadsheets, not GIMP.

I don't need GIMP anymore, and so want to unistall it. I have googled for guidance, but it keeps referring to the Software Center, which I cannot find in my Ubunutu 18.04, so

Where is the Software Center?, and

How do I best remove GIMP? (with or without the Software Center)

Please be aware that I am a beginner at Ubuntu (converted from Windows)

Thanks

Edit: Apology. I have Ubuntu-Mate 18.04. Does that explain why I cannot find the Software Center?

Comment: Try this: press Ctrl + Alt + T, enter `sudo apt remove gimp`, enter your password and press Y, and Gimp will be uninstalled.

Comment: also in nautilus change the default with `right click` -> `Properties` -> `Open With`

Comment: sudo apt remove gimp worked, thank you. Any suggestions on where the Software Center is, or how I can install it?

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu Mate does not ship with software center by default. It instead ships with [Software Boutique](https://snapcraft.io/software-boutique) through which you can install/uninstall software such as GIMP.

If you want to keep GIMP around for other purposes, you can select file associations in
Control Center -> (Under Common Tasks on left hand side, select 'Set Preferred Applications') -> Office ->  Select Spreadsheets, word processor, and Document Viewer to suit your preferences

This will prevent GIMP being used to open files that you don't want to use it for.

You can install ['Software'](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Software) from the 'More Software' tab inside the Software Boutique as well.

[image]

Comment: Ah yes, I see how to find it using the magnifying glass. I had just expected to see a list of installed software somewhere with a remove option (guess it is my Windows training at work here.) Thanks everyone.